# GATE JAPE rule annotate tokens contained by another

Tags: java, regex, gate

I am trying to create a rule in JAPE. ANNIE is identifying email ids. I am trying to identify all tokens which are sub-string of email id.

Ex: Following is an example of a document which has an email ID(abcd.xyz@gmail.com) and some other text ("cd x"). ANNIE NE Transducer marks the email id as `kind=email` I am trying to identify all other tokens which are sub-string of email Id. Here `cd` and `x` are the tokens which are substring of email id token. Tokens can lie outside the email id.

```
abcd.xyz@gmail.com ....
.....
cd x ....
....
```

Any solution?

Comment: Your question isn't clear to me.  Maybe include a snapshot of the text in the email, and then tell us what you are trying to match.

Comment: made edit. is it clear now?

Comment: So in this case, would `abcd.xyz@gmail.com` be an _input_, with the end goal flagging all strings which are _substrings_ of that email address as _output_?

Comment: `abcd.xyz@gmail.com` is part of document text. I run the document first through default ANNIE pipeline. At the end of the pipeline that email id is being marked as `kind=email`. I want to add another JAPE transducer after the ANNIE pipeline, which should identify all tokens which are sub-string of tokens marked as `kind=email`.

Comment: I'm not familiar with JAPE at all, but in any case our comments here made it clear what you are trying to do (I think).  Hopefully someone else can help you.

Answer (score 0):

Okay made some progress on this one. The challenge here is how to use text of one annotation to find another annotation. Here is my .jape file code

```
Imports: {
import my.pkg.*;
import static gate.Utils.*;
}

Phase: EmailID 
Input: Address 
Options: control = appelt  

Rule: EmailIDRule
(
{Address.kind==email}
):email
-->
:email{
    String email=stringFor(doc, emailAnnots).toString();
    doc.getFeatures().put("emilID",email);
}  

Phase: NameFromEmailID 
Input: Token SpaceToken Split
Options: control = appelt  

Rule: NameFromEmailID
(
(
{Token.category==NNP}
({SpaceToken})[1]
)[1,3]
):nam
-->
:nam{
String email = doc.getFeatures().get("emilID").toString();
String content=stringFor(doc, namAnnots).toString();
if(content!=null)
{
////write code to do wat ever u want and add features to annotation             
}
}
```